# Loop x times through function

Tags: python, loops, if-statement, tkinter, listbox

I have a program that uses selenium. In this program I have a tkinter GUI with a `Listbox`.

The list box that can be filled with names by entering the name in the entry field and adding it with a button.

After I filled my list I want to go over each name and perform a search loop.

This is my code so far (tried to simplify it for this example):

```
def loop_player_listbox():
    global bol_loop
    bol_loop = True
    if bol_loop is True:
        time.sleep(1)
        str_libo = listbox.get(0, tk.END)

        for i in str_libo:
            text_playername = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,('/html/body/main/section/section/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/input'))))
            text_playername.clear()
            text_playername.click()
            text_playername.send_keys(i)
            try:
                choose_player = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,("//span[@class='btn-text' and contains(text(),'"+i+"')]"))))
                choose_player.click()
            except:
                print('Player not found!')

            example()
```

In this example I want to go over each item in the list, search for the name on a URL and click it if the name was found and popped up in a specific xpath.

After that, and thats what I cant get done right, I want to perform a function in a loop.
The function should loop 5 times and then it should go over to the next na,e in my list box, and do the same (so actually for all names in my box it should perform this 5x times)

This is the loop to be performed:

```
def example(int_user_input_max_price, int_choose_speed): # buy only routine
    # start buy only mode
    global start_process, exit_tool
    exit_tool = False
    start_process = True
    if start_process is True:

        time.sleep(1)
        btn_search = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/main/section/section/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/button[2]')

        # set max price
        ipt_max_price = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
        ipt_max_price.click()
        time.sleep(1)
        ipt_max_price.send_keys(int_user_input_max_price)
        time.sleep(1)

        # Set min price
        int_min_price = 150

        # Set max players bought
        int_max_players_bought = 100
        int_players_bought = 0


        # Buy until 100 players were bought
        while int_players_bought < int_max_players_bought:
    else:
```

I don't go over the meaning of all my code, I just need to know, how could I make it possible that this `example()` is getting executed 5 times then go back to the next item in my listbox?

If any further input is needed please let me know.

EDIT1:

I have a list of football players. And with my code I am automating a Web Application of the game Fifa.

My program is searching for the player via the name from the list, and tries to buy it on the transfer market (`example()`).

I want to make it possible, that the user can add a few names to the listbox, and let the program loop through all of the items in the list. It should perform the `example()` for x times and then go back and do the same for the next item in the listbox.

I was thinking if a counter would help so it cunts += 1 after each loop through `example()`.
But I cant get the code togehter.

Comment: Could also include in summary what you would like to achieve?

Comment: added a summary what it should do ;-)

Comment: The answer below doesnt help?

Comment: No, because it had to take many aspects into account.
But I got it now. Have done a good amount of rewriting in my code. TY still